# Ruby on Rails - how to handle money and create multiple bookings with one payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building an events app using RoR. Currently a User is only able to book and pay for one space at a time. I'm trying to create a MVC method/process that allows one user to be able to book multiple spaces and for that booking to be processed with one payment. So, somebody who wants to book 5 spaces at £10 each will type in the quantity they require and on the payment page they will see the total amount required (£50) and proceed to pay. 
The code I've implemented so far simply isn't working. The issues centre on the right Model method to implement not only to do the multiplication (quantity * price) but also to handle the conversion of the £ symbol (string to float). 
This is the Booking Model -

**Booking.rb**

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    def total_amount

        #quantity.to_i * @price_currency.to_money
        quantity.to_i * strip_currency(event.price)
    end

    private

        def strip_currency(amount = '')
            amount.to_s.gsub(/[^\D\.]/, '').to_f
        end



end
```

And this is the Controller -

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity


    end




    def create
        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user
        @price = price
        @quantity = quantity
        @total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

        Booking.transaction do

            @event.reload
            if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
            end 
        end




        if @booking.save

            # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
            # #{} == puts a variable into a string
            Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
                card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end

        if @event.is_free?

            @booking.save!
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        end
    end

    #def total_amount
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity * @event.price
    #end

    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
    end



end
```

In the Event show view the user chooses the quantity they require here and then clicks on 'Book the Event'

**events.show.html.erb**

```
<form>
    number of spaces:
    <input type="number" placeholder="1"  min="1" value="1">

</form> 
<button><%= link_to "Book the Event", new_event_booking_path(@event) %></button>
```

This clicks through to the booking form/page which should show the total amount via the code below -

**Booking.new.html.erb**

```
<p>Total Amount   <%= @booking.total_amount %></p>
```

However, this is what is showing -

[image: Booking Page]

How do I make this work? Should I be implementing methods in Events model rather than bookings or both?

This is my schema - do I need to amend anything here?

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "event_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "stripe_token"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
t.integer  "quantity"
  end
```

Relevant events schema -

```
 t.integer  "number_of_spaces"
t.integer  "price"
t.boolean  "is_free"
t.integer  "price_cents",        default: 0,     null: false
t.integer  "price_pennies",      default: 0,     null: false
t.string   "price_currency",     default: "GBP", null: false
t.boolean  "happened",           default: false
```

end

I am using the money-rails gem only. I am not using monetize - do I need the monetize gem to make this work or is there something I can do without using it?

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is on the domain modeling level.

You have an **Event** model (the product), and **Booking** model (the line item) that models a single reservation. What you are missing is a model that corresponds to a group of bookings. Lets call it - Order.

In following the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) we also want a model that takes care of payments.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  def current_order
    self.orders.unpayed.last
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :orders, through: :bookings
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:open, :payed, :confirmed] #etc

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :events, through: :bookings
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :user, through: :order
end
```

Now you next issue is that you have shoved everything into your single `BookingsController`. Stop thinking about your application in terms of forms and think about it as a series of RESTful actions that a user can perform.

In this example creating orders is implicit. It also uses nested routes.

```
class BookingsController

  before_action :set_event

  # GET /events/:event_id/bookings/new
  def new
    @booking = @event.bookings.new
  end

  # POST /events/:event_id/bookings
  def create
    @order = current_user.current_order || current_user.order.create
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params) do |b|
       b.order = @order
    end

    if @booking.save
      redirect_to @event, notice: 'Your reservation has been added to your order'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private 

    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end 

    def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:a, :b, :c)
    end
end
```

We will also need a controller for orders:

```
class OrdersController
  # GET /orders
  def index
    @orders = current_user.orders
  end

  # GET /orders/:id
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In your layout you will want to add a link to the users current order. From that view the user should be able to complete the order by creating a payment.

```
class PaymentsController

  before_action :set_order

  # GET /orders/:order_id/payments
  def index
    @payments = @order.payments
  end

  # GET /orders/:order_id/payments/new
  def new
    @payment = @order.payments.new
  end

  # POST /orders/:order_id/payments
  def create
    @payment = @order.payments.new(payment_params)
    if @payment.save
      Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @booking.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
            card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")
      # @todo handle stripe failures!
      # @todo update Order if payment is succesful.
    else
      flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
      render :new
    end
  end
  private 

    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    def payment_params
      params.require(:payment)
    end
end
```

### What about the pounds and pennies?

Right now thats not really your biggest concern. Dealing with numeric input from users is indeed a tricky task and using a library like `monetize` means you can spend your time on other matters.

And dealing with user input is not the models job anyways in MVC. It's the controllers.

Comment: This answer is meant as a poke in the right direction since your approach has some rather fundamental flaws. This code is just meant as an example of concept and is not tested at all.

Comment: I appreciate such a detailed answer. I've hit a brick wall with this and had thought that my thinking was all wrong. I can look at this in more detail tonight. Thanks for the help.